# jquery animation not working correctly with setting coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate an element on click to specific coordinates. Here is my function:

```
                    function animateToCart(event) {

                    var domainBall = jQuery(this).parent(".addtocart").siblings(".domain-animation");
                    domainBall.addClass("yo");

                    var getCoordinates = document.getElementById("cart-domains-count").getBoundingClientRect();

                    var leftcoord = getCoordinates.left;
                    var rightcoord = getCoordinates.right;
                    var topcoord = getCoordinates.top;
                    var bottomcoord = getCoordinates.bottom;

                    domainBall.attr("styles","top:" + leftcoord + "px");


                    domainBall.animate({
                       'left': leftcoord,
                       'right': rightcoord,
                       'top': topcoord,
                       'bottom': bottomcoord
                    }, 500);

                    };
```

I call the function like so:

```
<span onClick="animateToCart()">Add To Cart »</span>
```

The div animates but not in the way I want and its behavious is pretty strange. It should animate to the coordinates of `#cart-domains-count` but instead animates to the right about 100px. Also it is not adding in the class which is very strange: `domainBall.addClass("yo");`This leads me to believe that maybe the scope of 'this' is maybe not correct but then I don't know why it would move only to the right. Really stuck on this one. Here is the css on the element aswell:

```
.domain-animation {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: Red;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="addtocart"><span onClick="animateToCart()">Add To Cart »</span></a>
<a href="#" class="register-this-domain">Register »</a>
<span class="domain-animation"></span>
```

Comment: Can you post HTML? Hard to tell if you are selecting what you expect with `var domainBall = jQuery(this).parent(".addtocart").siblings(".domain-animation");`

Comment: sure posted above

Answer (score 0):

All of the HTML elements are naturally displayed inline. Try changing them to `display: block`.